# Http data is not showed on my TextView [android]

Tags: android, http, textview

I' m trying to get data from google through HTTP request:

Main

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
TextView httpStuff;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.httpexample);
    httpStuff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.httpText);
    HTTP test = new HTTP();
    String returned = null;
    try {
        returned = test.getInternetData();
        httpStuff.setText(returned);
    } catch (Exception e) {com
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The HTTP clas is the following:

```
public class HTTP {

public String getInternetData() throws Exception{
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String data = null;
    try{
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI website = new URI("http://www.google.net");
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String l = "";
        String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while((l = in.readLine()) !=null){
            sb.append(l + nl );
        }
        in.close();
        data = sb.toString();
        return data;
    }finally {
        if (in != null){
            try{
                in.close();
                return data;

            }catch (Exception  e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

This is the console logcat:

> 04-27 19:31:58.063    2167-2191/com.example.briesanji.test D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
>   04-27 19:31:58.065    2167-2167/com.example.briesanji.test D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa687c600, tid 2167
>   04-27 19:31:58.103    2167-2167/com.example.briesanji.test D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
>   04-27 19:31:58.196    2167-2191/com.example.briesanji.test D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa687c7c0, tid 2191
>   04-27 19:31:58.207    2167-2191/com.example.briesanji.test I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>   04-27 19:31:58.283    2167-2191/com.example.briesanji.test D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
>   04-27 19:31:58.334    2167-2191/com.example.briesanji.test W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>   04-27 19:31:58.334    2167-2191/com.example.briesanji.test W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6868780, error=EGL_SUCCESS

The TextView does't show data but remains its default text ("loading data")
I ve tried to change `httpStuff.setText(returned);` with `httpStuff.setText("hello");` but nothing so I thought it was a problem of layout then I pulled out `httpStuff.setText("hello");` from the try method and it shows Hello.. So the problem is the try method of course but I don't know where I m wrong

Comment: Have you check that `getInternetData` isn't throwing an Exception? Instead of using `e.printStackTrace();` could you log your errors and post the logcat output?

Comment: how can I check that getInternetData isn't throwing an Exception?

Comment: By using the debbugger or using `Log.e()` instead of `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Sorry if I' m creating all these problems but I' m new in this kind of code. Anyway Log.e() is not working. it says "cannot resolve method 'e()' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not working because attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. For this reason you receive an `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

The simplest solution to resolve the issue is to use an `AsyncTask`:

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {

    TextView httpStuff;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);

        httpStuff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        new DownloadInternetData().execute();
    }

    public class DownloadInternetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            BufferedReader in = null;
            String data = null;
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                URI website = new URI("http://www.google.net");
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                request.setURI(website);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String l = "";
                String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(l + nl);
                }
                in.close();
                data = sb.toString();
                return data;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (in != null) {
                    try {
                        in.close();
                        return data;

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            httpStuff.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But the guy where I copied the code on youtube had not my problems and he didn't use AsyncTask

Comment: Maybe he used an older version of android. After Honeycomb you can't  perform a networking operation on its main thread. See the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

Comment: You are my hero Mattia you solved my problem. (Are you Italian??)

Comment: You're welcome. I see you're new to StackOverflow. If you feel the answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. (you guessed right, I am italian)

Comment: Oh my god me too.. You are really the best. Is there some way that allows me to add you as friend or so?